# When distributing items on a "Free, but make a Paypal donation if you wish" basis, how can I hide my street address from donors?

Tags: paypal

I am considering producing a small-circulation print-only magazine that will be distributed on a "Free, but send me a donation through Paypal if you wish" basis. The only way to make a payment will be to send it to me through Paypal using my email address.

If I do this, **is there a way to ensure that Paypal does not reveal my street address to donors?** If so, what is that way? (Note: I think the US English for what in British English is called "street address" is "mailing address".)

I say "donors" because the payments will be voluntary. I am not running a charity. If the sum of the payments is greater than my costs then I will have made a profit on which I will pay tax.

I am guessing the answer is yes, because otherwise all a bad person such as a stalker would have to do to find somebody's street address would be to send a very small amount of money to them through Paypal, using their email address, and if a Paypal account exists with that email address then click to say they are sending the money to "Family or friends", and a few seconds later they would receive an email from Paypal giving them the person's street address.

Comment: Use a PO box or a mail service (some pack-and-ship places offer a street address with a PO box type set up). What country is this in?

Comment: "Use a PO box" is technically a solution, but I meant how can I avoid providing any physical address. I'm in England, but if somebody gets a copy of the zine anywhere and they can donate through Paypal they will be welcome.

Comment: Aren't required to provide something like an imprint with a valid address anyway?

Comment: @glglgl - I think it's an urban legend that if you print a text then you have to put your address on it before you hand it to someone. Possibly I'm wrong, but there's no advice of that kind in say the _Writers' and Artists' Yearbook_.

Comment: @MaryDonald No, but if you call it a "magazine", I think it qualifies for what e. g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impressum writes under the UK description. (If my assumption of UK doesn't apply, please correct me.)

Comment: @glglgl - Interesting. Many thanks. I stand corrected. Maybe I will have to call the item an "agreement" or "message" rather than a "magazine" :-) I wonder when the last time was that somebody was prosecuted for omitting a printer's imprint or for distributing material that didn't have one. I may ask that question on the Law SE.

Comment: I wonder whether the printer's "address", though, could be their email address. I will ask that on the Law SE now.